# Passing a vector to a class by reference

Tags: c++, vector, openframeworks

I have a vector of ofTextures called images. I want to pass this to a class called Section by reference so it is not copied.

images is created in the header file. images has textures created inside of it, in the draw method with:

```
void ofApp::draw(){
if (video0.isFrameNew()){
    ofPixels pixels = video0.getPixels();
    images.emplace_back();
    images.back().allocate(pixels);
    }
}
```

I have a getTextures() function to return my images by reference I think the vector should still exist as I have initialised it before using it in this function.

```
vector<ofTexture> &ofApp::getTextures(){
    return  images;
}
```

I use this in the call to my constructor which is in a for loop in void `ofApp::setup()`

```
imSec.push_back(Section(getTextures());
```

I use getTextures() to pass the vector into my call to my constructor; however, when I run my program I don't seem to be able to draw the contents of the vector as I don't think my reference to the vector is working.

Any help on the correct way to pass by reference would be great.

Comment: Does `images` outlive the reference returned by `getTextures()`?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or it will really be impossible to answer in any meaningful way.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think this could be the problem as the vector may go out of scope.

Comment: @Elliot: then there isn't much we can do, as you know what your problem is. Either make sure that your vector outlives the reference, or return a copy, or use `std::unique_ptr`... it all depends on your situation.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo : ... or `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Pls at least mention where `images` comes from (where it is instantiated).

Answer (score 0):

The function `getTexture()` must return a reference to a vector that exists after the function returns. If you declare a vector inside that function and return a reference to it, it will not work, since the vector's memory in invalidated after the function returns.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I initialised my vector in my header file and then created items inside of it in my draw method so therefore doesn't it still exist after the function returns?